How can I prevent GoRouter redirect every time my Riverpod Futureprovider is updated?
I am using GoRouter for navigation and to handle redirect according to authentication state, which is working as expected. I am trying to also show a loading (splash) screen whilst asynchronous code is loaded from my FutureProvider. Whilst the data loads as the app is launched initially, the splash screen is shown (as expected). However, whenever data is modified (and state of the Future provider is therefore changed), I am redirected back to the initial location route. How can I prevent the redirection AFTER data has been loaded? I want to keep the current route location rather than be redirected back to the initial location.
Below is the main.dart code plus GoRouter router config.
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(ProviderScope(  
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: App()
    )),
  );
}

class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final GoRouter router = ref.watch(routerProvider);
     return MaterialApp.router(
         routerConfig: router,    
     );}
}



@riverpod
GoRouter router(RouterRef ref) {
  final auth = ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider);
  final appStartupState = ref.watch(appStartupProvider);

  return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    redirect: (context, state) {

      final bool isLoggedIn = auth.currentUser != null;
      final bool isLoggingIn = state.matchedLocation == '/login' ||
          state.matchedLocation == 'signUp';



      // should redirect the user to the sign in page if they are not logged in
      if (!isLoggedIn && !isLoggingIn) {
        return '/login';
      }

      // should redirect the user after they have logged in
      if (isLoggedIn && isLoggingIn) {
        return '/';
      }

      if (!appStartupState.hasValue) {
        return '/splash';
      }

      return null;

  },
    refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(auth.authStateChanges()),
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      //Splash Screen
      GoRoute(path: '/splash', builder: (context,state) => Splashscreen()),
      //Other routes...
       ],
  );
}

Below is the Future that waits for data to be loaded before returning a value that is used in GoRouter redirect
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Future<void> appStartup(Ref ref) async {
  ref.onDispose(() {
    ref.invalidate(combinedDataProvider);
  });
  await ref.watch(combinedDataProvider.future);
  //waits for combinedData to be loaded...
  //contains other providers for other data streams that require data
}

Perhaps this is not the best approach but I do not understand why I am redirected back to initial location when any data stream in the appStartUp Future is updated / modified
